# SearchView in Tabs ViewPager

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager, android-tabs, android-searchmanager

I am following [this](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-actionbarsherlock-viewpager-tabs-tutorial/) tutorial.

I want to add a `SearchView` in TabsViewpager as link: [Picture 1 http://www.uphinh.vn/image/stream/1386201.png](http://www.uphinh.vn/image/stream/1386201.png)

But my app ,SearchView not in TabsViewpager as link:[Picture 2 http://www.uphinh.vn/image/stream/1386202.png](http://www.uphinh.vn/image/stream/1386202.png)

I can't fix it.

This is my code:

- This is FragmentTab3.java:

  ```
  public class FragmentTab3  extends SherlockFragment  implements OnQueryTextListener {

      TextView mSearchText;
      @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
              Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          setHasOptionsMenu(true);

          // Get the view from fragmenttab1.xml
          View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenttab3, container, false);
          mSearchText =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.test);

          return view;
      }

      @Override
      public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
          super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
          setUserVisibleHint(true);
      }



  @Override
  public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

      inflater.inflate(R.menu.menutab3, menu);

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
          searchView.setQueryHint("Search");

          //searchView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
          searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
  }

      @Override
      public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          mSearchText.setText("Query so far:"+newText);
             mSearchText.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
          return false;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          mSearchText.setText("Searching for: " + query + "...");
             mSearchText.setTextColor(Color.RED);
          return false;
      }

  }
  ```
- This is fragmenttab3.xml

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/Fragment3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

- This is menutab3.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
          android:title="Action Bar Search"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText|collapseActionView"
          android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" /> 
  <item
        android:id="@+id/gamepad"
        android:title="@string/gamepad"
        android:icon="@drawable/gamepad"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    />
   <item
        android:id="@+id/camera"
        android:title="@string/camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/camera"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    />

</menu>
```

I using libs actionbarsherlock.

I CAN'T FIX IT.

Answer (score 5):

Here is simple example of searchview with viewpager

Interface **IDataCallback**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public interface IDataCallback {

    void onFragmentCreated( ArrayList<String> listData);
}
```

Interface **IFragmentListener**

```
public interface IFragmentListener {

    void addiSearch(ISearch iSearch);

    void removeISearch(ISearch iSearch);
}
```

Interface **ISearch**

```
public interface ISearch {

    void onTextQuery(String text);
}
```

your Activity **MainActivity**

```
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener, SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, IFragmentListener {

    //This is our tablayout
    private TabLayout tabLayout;

    //This is our viewPager
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    ArrayList<ISearch> iSearch = new ArrayList<>();
    private MenuItem searchMenuItem;
    private String newText;
    private PageAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<String> listData = null;

    IDataCallback iDataCallback = null;

    public void setiDataCallback(IDataCallback iDataCallback) {
        this.iDataCallback = iDataCallback;
        iDataCallback.onFragmentCreated(listData);
    }

    @Override
    public void addiSearch(ISearch iSearch) {
        this.iSearch.add(iSearch);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeISearch(ISearch iSearch) {
        this.iSearch.remove(iSearch);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Adding toolbar to the activity
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        listData = new ArrayList<>();
        //Initializing the tablayout
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

        //Adding the tabs using addTab() method
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab1"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab2"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab3"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        //Initializing viewPager
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        //Creating our pager adapter
        adapter = new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount(), newText);

        //Adding adapter to pager
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        //Adding onTabSelectedListener to swipe views
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();

        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }


    public void getDataFromFragment_one(ArrayList<String> listData) {
        this.listData = listData;
        Log.e("-->", "" + listData.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        this.newText = newText;
        adapter.setTextQueryChanged(newText);

        for (ISearch iSearchLocal : this.iSearch)
            iSearchLocal.onTextQuery(newText);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Main activity xml **activity_main**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- our toolbar -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <!-- our tablayout to display tabs  -->
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <!-- View pager to swipe views -->
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

page adpater **PageAdapter**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

public class PageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private String mSearchTerm;
    //integer to count number of tabs
    int tabCount;

    //Constructor to the class
    public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int tabCount, String searchTerm) {
        super(fm);
        //Initializing tab count
        this.tabCount= tabCount;
        this.mSearchTerm= searchTerm;
    }

    //Overriding method getItem
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        //Returning the current tabs
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Tab1 tab1 = Tab1.newInstance(mSearchTerm);
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                Tab2 tab2 = Tab2.newInstance(mSearchTerm);
                return tab2;
            case 2:
                Tab3 tab3 = Tab3.newInstance(mSearchTerm);
                return tab3;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    //Overriden method getCount to get the number of tabs
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabCount;
    }

    public void setTextQueryChanged(String newText) {
        mSearchTerm = newText;
    }
}
```

First Fragment **Tab1**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Tab1 extends Fragment implements ISearch {
    private static final String ARG_SEARCHTERM = "search_term";
    private String mSearchTerm = null;

    ArrayList<String> strings = null;
    private IFragmentListener mIFragmentListener = null;
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view;
        //Returning the layout file after inflating
        //Change R.layout.tab1 in you classes
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview1);
        strings = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            strings.add(String.valueOf(i));
        }
        strings.add("11");
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strings);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        mainActivity.getDataFromFragment_one(strings);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mSearchTerm = (String) getArguments().get(ARG_SEARCHTERM);
        }

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (null != mSearchTerm) {
            onTextQuery(mSearchTerm);
        }
    }

    public Tab1() {
    }

    public static Tab1 newInstance(String searchTerm) {
        Tab1 fragment = new Tab1();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(ARG_SEARCHTERM, searchTerm);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextQuery(String text) {
        arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(text);
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mIFragmentListener = (IFragmentListener) context;
        mIFragmentListener.addiSearch(Tab1.this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        if (null != mIFragmentListener)
            mIFragmentListener.removeISearch(Tab1.this);
    }
}
```

First Fragment xml **tab1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listview1">

</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Second Fragment **Tab2**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class Tab2 extends Fragment implements ISearch {

    private static final String ARG_SEARCHTERM = "search_term";
    private String mSearchTerm = null;

    private IFragmentListener mIFragmentListener = null;

    //Overriden method onCreateView
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //Returning the layout file after inflating
        //Change R.layout.tab1 in you classes
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, container, false);
        if(getArguments()!=null) {
            mSearchTerm = (String) getArguments().get(ARG_SEARCHTERM);
        }
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onTextQuery(String text) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(null!=mSearchTerm) {
            onTextQuery(mSearchTerm);
        }
    }

    public static Tab2 newInstance(String searchTerm){
        Tab2 fragment = new Tab2();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(ARG_SEARCHTERM, searchTerm);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mIFragmentListener = (IFragmentListener) context;
        mIFragmentListener.addiSearch(Tab2.this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        if(null!=mIFragmentListener)
            mIFragmentListener.removeISearch(Tab2.this);
    }
}
```

Second fragment xml **tab2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Tab 2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Third Fragment **Tab3**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


//Our class extending fragment
public class Tab3 extends Fragment implements ISearch, IDataCallback {

    private static final String ARG_SEARCHTERM = "search_term";
    private String mSearchTerm = null;

    ArrayList<String> strings = null;
    private IFragmentListener mIFragmentListener = null;
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = null;

    //Overriden method onCreateView
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view;
        //Returning the layout file after inflating
        //Change R.layout.tab1 in you classes
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3, container, false);
        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview2);
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setiDataCallback(this);
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strings);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mSearchTerm = (String) getArguments().get(ARG_SEARCHTERM);
        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextQuery(String text) {
        arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(text);
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (null != mSearchTerm) {
            onTextQuery(mSearchTerm);
        }
    }

    public static Tab3 newInstance(String searchTerm) {
        Tab3 fragment = new Tab3();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(ARG_SEARCHTERM, searchTerm);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mIFragmentListener = (IFragmentListener) context;
        mIFragmentListener.addiSearch(Tab3.this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        if (null != mIFragmentListener)
            mIFragmentListener.removeISearch(Tab3.this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentCreated(ArrayList<String> listData) {
        strings = listData;
    }
}
```

Third fragment xml **tab3.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listview2">

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Menu for Activity **menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        yourapp:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always"
        yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:title="Search"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: Nice way I want to say